# Allure 2 Report: How to specify the result framework when JUnit and CucumberJvm are both present in gradle

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, allure

The Allure report is being generated with 2 results for the same testcase, one for cucumber other for JUnit.

How to generate only the Cucumber reports ?

Executing the test with the following command:

```
gradelw test -Ptags=@Test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm"
```

###### build.gradle

(stackoverflow doesn't allow me to copy my whole build.gradle, so just copying the parts that seems related with this issue)

```
plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.9.6'
    id 'base'
    id 'java'
}

allure {
    version = '2.17.2'  // Latest Allure Version
    useJUnit5 {
        version = '2.17.2' // Latest Allure Version
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14

group 'org.test'
version '0.1'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    // Cucumber
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:6.11.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.11.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:6.11.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.11.0'

    // Allure
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.17.2'
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber6-jvm:2.17.2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7'

    // Junit
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2'))
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform{
        includeEngines 'junit-vintage'
    }
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    systemProperty("cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy", "long")
}

configurations {
    testCompile
}
```

##### allure report

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
You need to remove dependency allure-junit. Because allure-cucumber generate report and allure-junit also add results to this report.